# Laravel tests from the website

Tags: testing, laravel-5, web

I am looking for a way to make test cases that can be added to the admin dashboard of a laravel website. For example if a page on the website does contain a form to submit to the database in the dashboard the form can be tested for errors and even submission speed and if the form is collecting the right type of data integer field and string fields.

I click of a button and the forms and content will be tested.

I would really like to know how I can setup something like this but not really sure what to search for, any links are welcome to a website or message.

Best regards

Comment: and how would you test your tests? I think you are confusing validation with testing

Comment: I am not 100% sure how to explain but lets say the client entered details on the form and its not the correct Details that is validation with a set of rules on the form to set required types.

Comment: I am thinking more something like laravel dusk but on the admin panel to test the website for errors or creating a model to find problems on the website.

Comment: instead of a cmd console, a button can be used to run a test.

Comment: in theory you should be able to trigger artisan/phpunit/etc commands from php with `exec()`, you just have to create a controller for that too; I'm not so sure about how good solution is that

Comment: Thanks, That can work as a starting point.